# Const-correctness and hardware writes

Tags: c++, const-correctness

Say I have the following member function:

```
void CFoo::regWrite( int addr, int data )
{
  reg_write( addr, data ); // driver call to e.g. write a firmware register
}
```

Clearly, calling this function doesn't modify the internal state of the object it is called on. However, it changes the state of whatever this `Foo` instance *represents*.

In circumstances such as these, should `Foo::regWrite(int addr, int data)` be a const function?

Comment: Does the `CFoo` class represent the firmware? (i.e. could the firmware state be regarded as object state?)

Comment: AFAIK a method that does not change its object AND does not touch  any state would be what is called a "pure function". Technically, I would say, if the represented object is _part_ of the CFoo class, then don't make it a const function. If it's a globally defined object, make it one.

Comment: Assuming CFoo has other operations, will any of those be influenced by a call to regWrite? If yes, then it cleraly is part of the state, if not, then you should ask yourself why it is part of the class and not simply a free function, as it neither gets nor sets any kind of state related to that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide what the meaning is of "logically const" for the class `CFoo`, and that depends what the class is for.

If `CFoo` is construed as *referring to some data*, then it might make sense to be able to modify that data via a `const` instance of `CFoo`, in which case your member function would be `const`. For examples of this consider other types that refer to some data -- you can modify the referand of a `char *const` or a `const std::unique_ptr<char>`.

If `CFoo` is construed as *owning some data*, then it might make sense to forbid modification via a `const` instance of `CFoo`. For examples of this consider containers, where the elements are logically "part of the object's state" even when they aren't physically part of the object. So `vector::operator[]` has a const overload that returns a `const T&` rather than a `T&`, the `insert` member function is non-const, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to the programmer to define what 'const' shall mean for a class. With the specifier `mutable` you can even have a `const`object with changing values in a member. When it comes to hardware one might consider the configuration as the target for const correctness: as long as the configuration does not change the object can be considered constant.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of looking at this - the optimization angle, and the logic of this declaration. Which is more important is for you to decide.

#### Optimization

**EDIT**: I made some incorrect assumptions. It seems the compiler is not actually free to make the optimizations below, and will only make them by analyzing the *body* of the method to ensure no modifications occur (and even then only in simple cases).

> Having this `const` will allow the compiler to optimize a little bit
>   more. It knows that `regWrite` doesn't change any fields in the
>   object, so it can keep them if it was storing them in registers, and
>   do similar optimizations that rely on the objects *fields* not being
>   changed.
>
> This is really the only thing the compiler will depend on when you
>   make a definition like this, so having this `const` is OK and can
>   theoretically allow better performance.

#### Making logical sense

It feels unintuitive to have a `const` method whose whole purpose is a destructive change. The usual intuition a programmer has is that as long as I'm only calling const methods, the results of other `const` methods shouldn't change. If you violate this unwritten contract, expect people to be surprised - even if the compiler is OK with it.

I'm not sure if this will be violated here - it will depend on the other code in this class. However, if no other considerations are important (performance, etc.), `const` is (for me) mostly a marker on the interface which says "calling this does not change the state of this object", for a broad definition of "state".

This is murky ground however, and it is up to you what you consider a state change. If you think of your firmware object as representing a *link* to the internals, writing a register does not change anything about this *link* and is const. If you think of it as representing the state of the underlying registers, than writing to registers is a change of state.

Comment: "It knows that regWrite doesn't change any fields in the object" -- that's misleading. The compiler *must not* assume that just because the member function is `const`, it does not modify any data members. That optimization would not conform to the C++ standard. If the function can be inlined, so the compiler can see what the function actually does, then it might deduce that it doesn't modify any data members. Whether it can deduce this doesn't depend on whether the function is `const`, it depends what it does.

Comment: Verified this. It seems you are right, and I was wrong to assume that the compiler can depend on the 'constness' of a method keeping the object unchanged. This was a mistake on my part, I will edit to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue rises if you have pointers to other objects in your class: Your const method can then call non-const methods on the other object and thus modifiy it.

If you look at the hardware as as some other object referenced by your class, it would be perfectly valid to modify firmware settings (since only a "referenced" object is changed). If you want your class to "represent" the hardware (or part of it), I would rather suggest not to mark the method as `const`.

So I think it mainly depends how you designed your class.